# Disable URL creation for node in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In Drupal, I need to create a node that doesn't have a URL.

I have a node called "Collection". It is made up of Collection Pieces (also nodes). It's a list that's presented in a slider. I use nodereference inside the collection, referencing the pieces. I want the collection to have a URL, but not the pieces.

Anyone know how to disable the url creation for a node?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in drupal 6.  By default every single node is accessable through /node/[node-id] .

Drupal 7 has solved this problem by introducing the concept of [entities](http://drupal.org/node/1261744)

Your best bet is to use hook_nodeapi() to force access denied when someone tries to access these pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because the node is accessed by it's ID or by the alias created. Drupal must create id for each node (it's some kind of a reference to the node) .